# how to open an url and return data from there in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-view

I have developed simple custom odoo module. on button click action I wrote a simple method that should simply display data on the odoo screen. Module is getting installed successfully, but not performing required action so please help me. Thanks in advance.

**my button code in header tags**

```
*<header>
  <button name="get_data" type="object" string="Click" class="oe_highlight" />
</header>*
```

**my python method inside model.py**

```
*from odoo import models, fields, api
import requests
class gabzilAi(models.Model):
    _name = 'ai.gabzil'
    _description = 'Gabzil Odoo Module'
    fileName = fields.Text("File content")
    @api.one
    def get_data(self):
        myreq = requests.get("http://cake.gabzil.com/api/customers")
        textdata = myreq.text
        return textdata*
```

I am new to Odoo so not that much familiar with the things where i am making silly mistake...

Comment: May be you have to make a field in models to store textdata. then show it.

Comment: Yes!...I have tried that also by returning gabzilAi.fileName = myreq.text  but it's not sir...

Comment: make a field and store value which is returned by the function.